# Oracle coherence override cache-config's pof-config

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I need to start a java process which uses a library jar having pof-config specified in its cache-config file.

However that library pof-config file does not have all objects POF which I require. Those specific pof are stored in another pof-config file.

Is there anyway I can override pof-config which is mentioned in the cache-config file by providing -Dtangosol.pof.config="myown pof".xml runtime argument along with -Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig="library pof"?

At the moment when I try that, the specific pofs are not not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is yes.

The order of the configuration override is

1. use internal configuration
2. use run-time parameters
3. code

You need to specify -Dtangosol.pof.enabled=true.

[see oracle doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorial-1836512.html)

In our implementation we use following arfuments

```
-Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig=$COHERENCE_HOME/local-config.xml
-Dtangosol.pof.enabled=true
-Dtangosol.pof.config=$COHERENCE_HOME/pof-config.xml
```